# Определение расстояния между двумя не равноудаленными объектами на изображении

Tags: python, алгоритм, изображения, opencv

Допустим, у нас есть какая-то фотография. На ней изображены два объекта, расстояние между которыми нужно определить, зная, к примеру, реальный размер этих объектов. Как это возможно сделать?

Есть предположение: Каким-то образом (КАК?) вытащить угол альфа, и посчитав расстояния от объектива до каждого из объектов, найти третью сторону.

Пример изображения прикрепил. Нужно найти расстояние от машины до дома)

[image: Под глазом понимается объектив, от которого прямыми идут расстояния до объектов: до машины и до дома.]

Answer (score 0):

Объяснить в ответе на форуме без выкладок и формул - врят-ли удастся. Но задача известная. 
Вот ссылки для начала. Думаю - помогут въехать в тему. Ну а далее - уже самостоятельно.

https://bootsector.livejournal.com/43436.html

[http://old.msun.ru/Vector/СФЕРИЧЕСКАЯ%20ГЕОМЕТРИЯ/Расстояние_по_фотографии.htm](http://old.msun.ru/Vector/%D0%A1%D0%A4%D0%95%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%AF%20%D0%93%D0%95%D0%9E%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%AF/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8.htm)

https://qna.habr.com/q/560722

http://www.computeroptics.smr.ru/KO/PDF/KO35-2/21_Geidarov.pdf